# Redirect to folder only if root from other site referrer

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, directory, documentroot

I have a redirect from root to subfolder. If user visits `https://example.com` it redirects to `https://example.com/subfolder`. But I want it not to redirect if referrer is my site, so user can reach root page.

For example:

1. User visits `https://example.com`
2. It redirects to `https://example.com/subfolder`
3. User visits `https://example.com/subfolder/file.html`
4. there's a link on this page to `https://example.com` and he follows it
5. It must open `https://example.com` and not to redirect

Here is my .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ https://example.com/
```

Please, give me an advice to solve the problem, I'm poor on .htaccess rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here is my .htaccess:
>
> ```
> RedirectMatch ^/$ https://example.com/
> ```

This obviously doesn't redirect to `/subfolder` as you suggest. It would create an endless redirect loop.

However, you can't check the `Referer` header using a mod_alias `RedirectMatch`. You need to use mod_rewrite (or an `<If>` expression) instead.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://example\.com($|/)
RewriteRule ^$ /subfolder/ [R,L]
```

Note that the check for an *empty* URL-path (ie. `^$`) is intentional. The `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not match the slash prefix.

Comment: That's it, thanks. But If I user folows example.com link from example/subfolder/file.html it would redirect to example.com/subfolder/

Comment: @StasPonomaryov Sorry, there was a typo in my answer. It should be `%{HTTP_REFERER}`, not `${...}`! I've updated my answer.